# VB.NET Automate combobox item drawing

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a few font comboboxes in my application.

I can initiate them from within a single sub, namely:

```
 Public Sub InitFontCombo(ByVal uCombo As ComboBox)

        uCombo.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        uCombo.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif, 11.25pt", 11.25)
        uCombo.ItemHeight = 20
        Dim objFontFamily As FontFamily
        Dim objFontCollection As System.Drawing.Text.FontCollection

        objFontCollection = New System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection()
        For Each objFontFamily In objFontCollection.Families
            modControls.ComboAddItem(uCombo, objFontFamily.Name)
        Next

    End Sub
```

However, I still need to the DrawItem call to each form like this:

```
Private Sub cboFont_DrawItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboFontName.DrawItem

        e.DrawBackground()
        If (e.State And DrawItemState.Focus) <> 0 Then
            e.DrawFocusRectangle()
        End If
        Dim objBrush As Brush = Nothing
        Try
            If e.Index > -1 Then
                objBrush = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
                Dim sFontName As String = Me.cboFontName.Items(e.Index).ToString
                Dim nFont As Font = Nothing
                Dim nFontFamily = New FontFamily(sFontName)
                If nFontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular) Then
                    nFont = New Font(nFontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Regular)
                ElseIf nFontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold) Then
                    nFont = New Font(nFontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Bold)
                ElseIf nFontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic) Then
                    nFont = New Font(nFontFamily, 14, FontStyle.Italic)
                End If
                e.Graphics.DrawString(sFontName, nFont, objBrush, e.Bounds)
            End If
        Finally
            If objBrush IsNot Nothing Then
                objBrush.Dispose()
            End If
            objBrush = Nothing
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Is there some way to automate both of these calls?
Or do I need to put the combobox in a usercontrol and do everything in there?

Comment: whats the point of a Try without a Catch?  are you wanting to have a procedure which handles multiple CBOs on *different* forms or the same form - you can hook multiple controls to a single event handler: just extended the `Handles....` clause on the event procedure

Comment: @Plutonix 1) I did not write that code, but I also don't see what's wrong with having a Try without a Catch. What is your point? 2) The font combos are not on the same form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same custom behaviour from multiple controls then you should create a custom control.  Declare a new class named `FontComboBox` and have it inherit the `ComboBox` class.  You would then put the initialisation inside the class and also override the `OnDrawItem` method inside the class instead of handling the `DrawItem` event outside.